# Login to Serenity-is webapp

Tags: authentication, post, request, serenity

I have a Serenity-is webapp. What I want to do is to use it's API from an external app.
To do it, I am trying to provide an external login, but I don't understand the required request from Serenity-is webapp.
The default endpoint is `~/Account/Login` so I made a post call to `my-url.com/account/login` with this payload in the body:

```json
{
    'Username' : 'myUsername',
    'Password' : 'myPassword'
}
```

but everytime I receive:

> error 400: Bad request

I'm sure that credentials are right and probably I'm missing some key concept about Serenity's login authentication. I would expect to receive status 200 and maybe a token in the response or something similar, but I'm not sure about it.

Comment: From where did you get this payload schema, and are you sure it's correct? Can you share a link to the documentation on which you're basing this understanding?

Comment: I reconstructed it by Serenity-is code. What I did, was searching the point in the default code it was called and I found this code `serviceCall({
    url: resolveUrl('~/Account/Login'),
    request: request,
    onSuccess: () => {
        this.redirectToReturnUrl();
    },
    onError: response => {
    /* ... */
    }
})`. This should be the call made by pressing login button in the Serenity-is default project. Debugging, I found that request have that structure so I tried same post, but it did not work.

Comment: I've searched in official documentation here `https://serenity.is/docs/`, but I did not found (or understand) what I need

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the answer.
By default, Serenity use bearer tokens.
It require to send at first a POST request with a bearer token in the header (without this, it will always be status 400, you can use something like `"Bearer abcdefg123456789hijklmno"`, I suggest to use a Guid generator so you can make unique codes) and a body like `{ "Username": "user", "Password": "pass" }`, in this way the server will answer with status 200. The server will take the bearer token and will make a "CSRF-TOKEN", but will not put it in the answer, so it's necessary to make a GET to "/" endpoint and in the cookies, into "set-cookies" there is the "CSRF-TOKEN". After parsing the cookies string and extrapolating the "CSRF-TOKEN" it will have to be put in the header in every following call.
I was not sending the bearer token expecting it as an answer, instead it had to be generated by the caller.